# Xcode 8 stuck on "Signing Product"

Tags: xcode8, cocoa-touch

I m building a SiriKit test application, I have 4 targets in project:

[image]

The CocoaTouch Framework build successfully, but when I build the app(The Zero Target) Xcode always stuck on:

[image]

I set "Automatically manage signing" for all targets, still not worked.(According to this [LINK](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4884))

Any help would be appreciated!